# Parallel.For causing huge context switching overhead for this case... Why?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I am experimenting with the new parallelism tools in .NET 4, by calculating Pi using Monte Carlo methods.

(The actual algorithm is not so important, but for clarity's sake, here it is:

1. Pick `numIterations` random points inside a unit square.
2. Count the number of these points that lie within a circle that is bounded by that square (i.e. the points whose distance from the centre of the square is less than 0.5)
3. Then, for very large `numIterations`, `PI=4 * iterationsInsideCircle / numIterations`.)

I have a method `int ThrowDarts(int numDarts)` which picks `numDarts` random points inside the unit square (described above) and returns the number of points which lie within the unit circle:

```
    protected static int ThrowDarts(int iterations)
    {
        int dartsInsideCircle = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++)
        {
            double pointX = random.NextDouble() - 0.5;
            double pointY = random.NextDouble() - 0.5;

            double distanceFromOrigin = Math.Sqrt(pointX*pointX + pointY*pointY);
            bool pointInsideCircle = distanceFromOrigin <= 0.5;

            if (pointInsideCircle)
            {
                dartsInsideCircle++;
            }
        }
        return dartsInsideCircle;
    }
```

Essentially, in each of my different implementations (which each use different parallel mechanisms), I am writing different ways of throwing and counting the darts inside the circle.

For example, my single threaded implementation is simply:

```
    protected override int CountInterationsInsideCircle()
    {
        return ThrowDarts(_numInterations);
    }
```

I also have this method for one of my parallel algorithms:

```
    protected override int CountInterationsInsideCircle()
    {
        Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[_numThreads];

        for (int i = 0; i < _numThreads; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ThrowDarts(_numInterations/_numThreads));
        }

        int iterationsInsideCircle = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _numThreads; i++)
        {
            iterationsInsideCircle += tasks[i].Result;
        }

        return iterationsInsideCircle;
    }
```

Hopefully you get the picture.

Here, I get to my conundrum. The `Parallel.For` version I am writing causes massive amounts of context switching. The code is below:

```
    protected override int CountInterationsInsideCircle()
    {
        ConcurrentBag<int> results = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        int result = 0;

        Parallel.For(0, _numInterations,
                     // initialise each thread by setting it's hit count to 0
                     () => 0,
                     //in the body, we throw one dart and see whether it hit or not
                     (iteration, state, localState) => localState + ThrowDarts(1),
                     // finally, we sum (in a thread-safe way) all the hit counts of each thread together
                     results.Add);

        foreach(var threadresult in results)
        {
            result+=threadresult;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The version using `Parallel.For` does work, but very, very slowly, because of the aforementioned context switching (which does not occur in the previous two methods).

Is anyone able to enlighten me as to why this may be happening?

Comment: How many processors does the machine have?

Comment: ThrowDarts(1)?  Bump up that number so you don't burn up a thread executing a couple of nanoseconds of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually found the solution to the question.

Previously, in my ThrowDarts method, I was creating a new `Random` with every call (this was because the `Random` class is not thread safe.)

However, turns out, this is relatively expensive. (At least, it is when only performing one dart throw, such that we generate a new `Random` for each iteration.)

Thus, I have modified my `ThrowDarts` method to take a `Random` which the caller creates, and modified my LoopState to contain it's own Random.

Therefore, each thread in the `Parallel.For` contains it's own `Random`. My new implementation is as follows:

```
    protected override int CountInterationsInsideCircle()
    {
        ConcurrentBag<int> results = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        Parallel.For(0, _numInterations,
                     // initialise each thread by setting it's hit count to 0
                     () => new LoopThreadState(),
                     // in the body, we throw one dart and see whether it hit or not
                     (iteration, _, localState) =>
                        {
                            localState.Count += ThrowDarts(1, localState.RandomNumberGenerator);
                            return localState;
                        },
                     // finally, we sum (in a thread-safe way) all the hit counts of each thread together
                     result => results.Add(result.Count));

        int finalResult = 0;
        foreach (int threadresult in results)
        {
            finalResult += threadresult;
        }

        return finalResult;
    }
```

I guess the context switching metric was a bit of a red herring, and a simple profile would have done the trick. Nice curve ball, .NET, nice. Anyway, lesson learned!

Thanks all,
Alex

Comment: Did you spot me retunring your curve ball earlier? In my profiling of it on mono I used the multipliers 50000 and 10000 in the first two lines :) 10000 dartsPerIter meant I used 1 Random() instance per 10000 darts. So I more or less automatically paved over the problem. I just assumed that somehow you temporarily put the number '1' in there not for 'real' use ... :)

Comment: While this may be performant it's unlikely to be correct. You need to be careful using Random from multiple threads even with different seeds. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ade. This method actually creates a new Random for each thread as part of the localstate object, so this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess - in contrast to the other implementations that locally keep track of their results and then combine them at the end, the parallel for is using a shared set of results which would pay a heavier price in order to keep it thread-safe, not to mention it's probably suffering from cache-line sharing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx).

Comment: Is it?

My understanding of the way I've written it is that each thread throws some darts and adds the results to it's local state. Then, when the framework is done with the thread, it adds its result to the concurrentbag. Then, once Parallel.For has terminated, it sums up all the results (on the main thread). As far as I can see, this has no shared results (except for the bag, which is unavoidable) between threads, and shouldn't suffer much of a cache hit.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I got confused and jumbled the overloads.

Comment: BTW ThrowDarts(1) is going to have a lot of overhead and give you incorrect results because of creating a new Random every time.  That could be it depending on whether those use some global state.  The incorrectness will be because Randoms created within the same time quantum (millisecond?) give the same sequence.

Comment: Just posted my own answer, then saw this. That's precisely the flaw, see my new implementation below. Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
*Couldn't help but running the same benchmarks on my home PC (linux 32bit, Q9550) with mono 2.8.2 as well just for fun*:

```
[mono] /tmp @ dmcs MonteCarlo.cs 
[mono] /tmp @ time mono ./MonteCarlo.exe 
Yo
Approx: 392711899/500000000 => Pi: 3.141695192

real    0m28.109s
user    0m27.966s
sys 0m0.152s
[mono] /tmp @ dmcs MonteCarlo.cs # #define PARALLEL added
[mono] /tmp @ time mono ./MonteCarlo.exe 
Yo
Approx: 392687018/500000000 => Pi: 3.141496144

real    0m8.139s
user    0m31.506s
sys 0m0.064s
```

---

So yes, it does seem to scale as expected. 
Thanks for letting me actually put this to 'use' on mono. It was on my 'TODO' list for too long, and it works like a charm!

#### Original post

I just timed it using mono 2.8.2 on a dualcore (E5300) windows XP

Using the parallel version (#define PARALLEL) it ran in 40s

Using the sequential version (not defining PARALLEL) it took about 45s.

So I'm not seeing your measured overhead; or at least I'm not seeing a slowdown. I'm also missing the speedup, like you do.

In the parallel run I saw both CPUs pegged at 100%, whereas the singlethreaded version used approx. 50% of both CPUs average.

```
#define PARALLEL
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        const int _numInterations = 50000;
        const int _dartsPerIter = 10000;

        protected static int ThrowDarts (int iterations)
        {
            Random random = new Random ();
            int dartsInsideCircle = 0;
            for (int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++) {
                double pointX = random.NextDouble () - 0.5;
                double pointY = random.NextDouble () - 0.5;

                double distanceFromOrigin = Math.Sqrt (pointX * pointX + pointY * pointY);
                bool pointInsideCircle = distanceFromOrigin <= 0.5;

                if (pointInsideCircle) {
                    dartsInsideCircle++;
                }
            }
            return dartsInsideCircle;
        }
        protected int CountInterationsInsideCircle ()
        {
            ConcurrentBag<int> results = new ConcurrentBag<int> ();
            int result = 0;

            // initialise each thread by setting it's hit count to 0
            //in the body, we throw one dart and see whether it hit or not
            // finally, we sum (in a thread-safe way) all the hit counts of each thread together
#if PARALLEL
            Parallel.For (0, _numInterations, () => 0, (iteration, state, localState) => localState + ThrowDarts (_dartsPerIter), results.Add);
#else
            for (var i =0; i<_numInterations; ++i)
                results.Add(ThrowDarts (_dartsPerIter));
#endif

            foreach (var threadresult in results) {
                result += threadresult;
            }

            return result;
        }
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yo");
            var inside = new MainClass ().CountInterationsInsideCircle ();
            Console.WriteLine("Approx: {0}/{1} => Pi: {2}",
                               inside, _numInterations * _dartsPerIter,
                               (4.0*inside)/(1.0*_numInterations*_dartsPerIter));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when _numThreads == _numIterations in your manual Task case?  The first approach specifically splits it into _numThreads, where the Parallel.For version will always create _numIterations Tasks, with one iteration each.  Depending on how many iterations, this can overwhelm the thread pool and negate any benefit of parallelism due to the overhead of contention for the pool and its associated locking.

Parallel.For is well-suited when each operation is reasonably expensive and can be computed independently.  The issue in this case is that running the computation for a single iteration is a cheap operation, so the overhead begins to dominate the time for each task.  You can make your Parallel.For version equivalent by using _numThreads and _numIterations / _numThreads, just as you did for the manual Task version.